# Is it possible to propagate annotations in Dagger 2?

Tags: dagger-2

I have these classes:

```
class Storage {
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
  public @interface Songs {}

  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
  public @interface Movies {}

  @Inject
  public Storage(
    @Songs Blobstore songsStore,
    @Movies Blobstore moviesStore) {
// ...
}

class Blobstore {
  @Inject
  public Blobstore(File path) {
// ...
```

It seems reasonable to provide only the paths, like this:

```
@Provides
@Songs
public static File songPath() { return new File("/sdcard/songs"); }
@Provides
@Movies
public static File moviePath() { return new File("/sdcard/movies"); }
```

But if I do this, I get the error message: `File is bound multiple times`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: is `@Songs` a `@Qualifier`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I can make `@Songs` a `@Qualifier`. It still fails with the same message.

Comment: Did you annotate `@interface Songs` with `@Qualifier`, or did you replace it in your module? It will work if you use qualifiers correctly. If it doesn't, please update your question with your code.

Comment: OK, updated the question to add the annotation definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Qualifier` annotations [need to be runtime-retained to comply with JSR-330](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html) (emphasis mine):

> A qualifier annotation:
>
> - is annotated with @Qualifier, **@Retention(RUNTIME)**, and typically @Documented.
> - [ ... ]

Though Dagger code generation happens at compile time, it also requires compliance with JSR-330, which means that Dagger won't be affected by non-compliant qualifier annotations.

Comment: I did so. The new messages are: `File cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.` and `@Songs Blobstore  cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: @Lev Then it's working! You have an `@Inject` annotation on Blobstore, and now that your Qualifiers actually work, you'll need to bind `@Songs Blobstore` to `Blobstore` and `@Movies Blobstore` to `Blobstore`, or whichever implementations or scopes you need.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find proper information on what purpose these annotations have? I've read the source but it's not very enlightening. What do they do in terms of Dagger?

Comment: @Florian: The [User's Guide section on Qualifiers](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide#qualifiers) is where I'd look first. It's not too complicated: Qualifiers let you distinguish between bindings when you want multiple objects in your graph with the same type, by annotating the fields or parameters with a "qualifier annotation". The meta-annotation `@Qualifier` lets you create your own qualifier annotations by annotating your own annotation with `@Qualifier`, but you can also use existing ones like `@Named` without defining your own.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I wasn't clear. Probably because it was very late. I was actually talking about `@Documented` and `@Retention`. They are difficult to understand but I think I have an idea now.

Comment: @Florian: Ah. [`@Documented`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Documented.html) simply affects the Javadoc tool, indicating the annotation should show up in the documentation of the annotated items. [`@Retention`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) has a more practical effect: whether the annotation should be compiled into class files, and whether it should then be visible at runtime through reflection. See the [RetentionPolicy docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html).